# ldap_modify function through access violation?

Tags: c++, c, windows

i am trying  to modify the AD attribute value using ldap_modify function...

the code is below...

```
    LDAPMod *list_of_attrs[1]={0};
    char *Password[] = {"Password2"};
    LDAPMessage *result=NULL;
    int msgid;
    int rc=0;   
    LDAPMod attribute2;     

    attribute2.mod_type = (PCHAR)"Password number";
    attribute2.mod_op = LDAP_MOD_REPLACE;
    attribute2.mod_vals.modv_strvals=Password;
    list_of_attrs[0] = &attribute2;


    wchar_t dnName[100]={0};
    char *dn = "CN=test,CN=Users,DC=raja,DC=com";
    mbstowcs(dnName,dn, 100);
    PWCHAR dnNameval = (PWCHAR)malloc(sizeof(PWCHAR) * 20);
    wcscpy(dnNameval,dnName);

    msgid=ldap_modify(pLdapConnection,(const PCHAR)dnNameval, list_of_attrs);
```

but,when it comes to last line(msgid)access violation exception occured..

****Unhandled exception at 0x76f693ac in AD2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.****

kindly help me to resolve that...
thanks in advance.

Comment: Casting a wide string to a narrow string is a bad idea.

Comment: It could very well be the cast: `(const PCHAR)dnNameval`.

Comment: I'm not good at the LDAP functions in question, but besides the mixed use or `char` and `wchar_t`, how does the function know how long the arrays `list_of_attrs` and `Password` are?

Comment: Now my only problem is list_of_attrs   attribute2.mod_type = (PCHAR)"Password number";
    attribute2.mod_op = LDAP_MOD_REPLACE;
    attribute2.mod_vals.modv_strvals=Password;
    list_of_attrs[0] = &attribute2; how could i pass the value to this arguments....Mainly attribute2.mod_vals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may guess from **location 0xcccccccc** that the crash occurs due to an uninitialized pointer. When reading the code, `pLdapConnection` appears to be that pointer.

**Update**

After reading the OP comment, now I can see that the problem is in the 3rd argument which is, quoting MSDN, **a null-terminated array of modifications to make to the entry**.
Therefore, the correct usage should be e.g.

```
LDAPMod attribute2;     
// Initialize attribute2
............
LDAPMod *list_of_attrs[2]={&attribute2, 0};
```

That is, the size of the array should be one more than the number of entries you'd like to define and the last array item should be NULL.

Comment: Andrey,i did check 3 arguments in ldap_modify function,to set into null,after that,give values to each arguments,only 3rd one gives  exception...so i surely said "list of attrib' only problem...how to i pass the values to 3rd argument,especially attrib.mod_vals...

Comment: i hava aproblem in attrib.mod_vals...because its have  a struct..that struct have  a union...the structure is          typedef struct ldapmodA {
     ULONG     mod_op;
     PCHAR     mod_type;
     union {
        PCHAR  *modv_strvals;
        struct berval   **modv_bvals;
    } mod_vals;
} LDAPModA, *PLDAPModA;...now anyone can tell how to pass the attrib.mod_vals?

Answer (score 1):

Just using mod_values to mod_vals...

mod_values is defined in winldap.h...

```
char *Password[] = {"Password2",NUll};

    attribute2.mod_type = (PCHAR)"Password number";
    attribute2.mod_op = LDAP_MOD_REPLACE;
    attribute2.mod_values=Password;

    ldap_modify(pLdapConnection,dnNameval, list_of_attrs);
```

Now,the ldap_modify function works fine & modify the value to attribute in Active Directory...

thanks for your support

Sanju